# Redirect to custom URL after user clicks 'Proceed to checkout' at the cart page (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When user clicks 'Proceed to checkout' at the cart page, I would like to send him to custom URL. I used this filter in functions.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'dj_redirect_checkout');

function dj_redirect_checkout($url) {
     global $woocommerce;
     $checkout_url = 'http://my-custom-url.com';
     return  $checkout_url; 
}
```

However, in this case this filter is triggered on the checkout page as well and I would like to trigger it on the Cart page and after the click 'Proceed to checkout' only.

Please, advise.

Thank you,

Comment: Sorry ! But I am confused .. Above code is working or not ? If yes, Is It taking you to two pages ?

Comment: What it mean? -However, in this case this filter is triggered on the checkout page as well and I would like to trigger it on the Cart page and after the click 'Proceed to checkout' only.

Comment: above code is working - but it works on 2 pages (cart and checkout). i would like to make it work only on cart page after user clicks 'Proceed to checkout'

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is, use [conditional tags](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/) in your code :

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'dj_redirect_checkout');

    function dj_redirect_checkout($url) {
         global $woocommerce;
         if(is_cart()){
              $checkout_url = 'http://my-custom-url.com';
         }
         else { 
         //other url or leave it blank.
         }
         return  $checkout_url; 
    }
```

**EDITED** :

If you want to redirect users to custom URL after click on Add to card button then you can use below code:

```
    add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');

    function redirect_to_checkout() {
        global $woocommerce;
        $checkout_url = 'http://my-custom-url.com';
        return $checkout_url;
    }
```

**Second Edit** :

What you can do for that is simply make on template for check out page :

```
    <?php 
    /**
    * Template Name: Custom Template
    *
    *Custom Template for the woocommerce checkout page
    *
    */

    get_header();?>

    <a href="?page_id=6">Click Me! </a>

    <?php 
    get_footer();
    ?>
```

Here in above code, I have made template with name of **custom Template** and save it with the `wtemplate.php` in the theme folder.

Next step is to **Create New Page**. I have created new page with the name of **Simple Template**(You can name it whatever you want). And in sidebar, there is option of template(you can see below image for reference) where I have selected **Custom Template** as a template.

[image]

Now Go to the **Dashboard > WooCommerce > Settings > Checkout ** and in that, there is option of selecting checkout page(You can find in below picture). Select the page that you have made(I have made **Simple Template** as you can see in above code) and save it.

[image]

Now whenever user will click on `Proceed to Checkout`, they will redirect to that custom template.In custom template, you can link to the `woocommerce default checkout page`(In my case, It is having page_id=6).

Hope it helps you.If you have any doubt related to this, you can give comment.

Comment: thanks, but it sends me just to the empty page (condition not working)

Comment: It is sending you somewhere, it means it is working. You need to debug it in order to make it work. Just start with echo :)

Comment: no, it means that it doesn't see an is_cart() condition and sends me to empty page with cart URL because of empty else {} condition

Comment: Then why don't you put woocommerce's default URL there. I don't know what you want to achieve but you can put woocommerce's checkout page there like : `else{ $checkout_url= 'woocommercesdefaultpage.com' }`

Comment: thanks for the response. my idea is to send user to custom page after he clicks 'Proceed to checkout' (where he will be able to go to standard woocommerce checkout page). as far as i see, of i add filter for woocommerce_get_checkout_url, it is processed across all pages (say, for cart page and for place order page with billing and shipping details). All I need is to apply this filter only to 'Proceed to checkout' button at the cart page. Please advise.

Comment: yes, your second snippet of code is exactly what I need but for 'Proceed to checkout' click an the cart page.

Comment: `'Proceed to checkout' click an the cart page.` I didn't get your this line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66408/discussion-between-user1192422-and-rohil-phpbeginner).

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner  this is a really detailed answer.Thank you.you helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did a combination of creating a custom page and setting it as the checkout page, and also returning the default WC checkout page to the filter based on certain conditions.